# how to Delete post at the nested path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, nested, destroy

I have some trouble with my code. Could you help me?

## views/topics/show.html.slim

```
- if current_user == post.user
  = link_to 'Удалить комментарий',forum_topic_post_path(@forum, @topics, @posts, @post),
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

## controllers/post_controller.rb

```
def destroy
    @forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
    @topic = Topic.find params[:topic_id]
    @post.user = current_user
    @post = Post.find(params[:id]).destroy
end
```

## error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#destroy

Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#

@post = Post.find(params[:id]).destroy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two mistake in your code.

1) Try change `@post` object to `post` in your `link_to` like below.

Also not sure about your @topics object, It should hold a single record.

```
- if current_user == post.user
  = link_to 'Удалить комментарий',forum_topic_post_path(@forum, @topics, post),
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

2) In your controller try changes destroy action as below:

```
def destroy
  @forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
  @topic = Topic.find params[:topic_id]
  @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id]).destroy
end
```

Considering you have has_many relationship in user and posts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `post_path` correct me if I am wrong

```
= link_to 'Удалить комментарий', post_path(post,:forum_id =>@forum.id, :topic_id =>@topic.id),
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

or

```
= link_to 'Удалить комментарий', forum_topic_post_path(@forum, @topics, post),
    method: :delete,
    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

If I have got you correctly this should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
- if current_user == post.user
 = link_to 'Удалить комментарий',forum_topic_post_path(@forum, @topics, @post),
   method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

**Controller**

```
before_action :check_user, only: [:destroy]

def destroy
    @forum = Forum.find params[:forum_id]
    @topic = Topic.find params[:topic_id]
    @post.destroy 
end

private

def check_user
  if current_user != @product.user
    redirect_to root_url, alert: "Sorry, This Post belongs to someone else !"
  end
end
```

(mne kajetsa tebe ne nado ispolzovat "current_user" dla udalenie post.)